# How to download all modules in the background, right after main page load in Angular 14

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend

Making lazy loading per module is pretty easy in Angular.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'customers',
    loadChildren: () => import('./customers/customers.module').then(m => m.CustomersModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'orders',
    loadChildren: () => import('./orders/orders.module').then(m => m.OrdersModule)
  }
];
```

But this forces to me to download the module when I navigate to it the first time.

Is it possible to download ALL modules in the background after the first page load?.

Comment: Well this is the whole purpose of lazy loading. If you don't need it then use eager loading instead. The code of your modules will be included in the initial chunk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can by setting up a `preloadingStrategy` or you can create your own
custom strategy.
[Angular docs link](https://angular.io/api/router/PreloadAllModules)